# How can I make my decimal variable 0 if the parse fails?

Tags: c#, npoi

I am using the NPOI lib to read an excel file and one column has a price that is not always set, when the cell is empty my code crashes so I am trying to see how I can make my variable 0 if the cell is empty or if the parse fails, whichever is the best way

my code is as follows

```
 decimal grossPrice = decimal.Parse(row.GetCell(10).ToString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit depending on the C# version you are using you can use `TryParse`, which is also available vor `int`, `float`, etc.:

```cs
decimal grossPrice = decimal.TryParse(row.GetCell(10).ToString(), out var val) ? 
                     val : your_default_value; //your_default_value = 0 in your case
```

or

```cs
decimal val = 0;
if (decimal.TryParse(row.GetCell(10).ToString(), out val)
{
   //value set
   //not needed, but handy for the completeness of this example
}

else
{
   //value not set (error; assign default value to val)
   //not needed, but handy for the completeness of this example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

> When this method returns, contains the Decimal number that is equivalent to the numeric value contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed.

```
decimal grossPrice = 0;
decimal.TryParse(row.GetCell(10).ToString(), out grossPrice);
```